# Q-automorphisms determind by associates to id-element?

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory

Let's say you consider the Galois group of $G(\mathbb{Q[\sqrt{3},\sqrt{2},i]}/\mathbb{Q})$. This is just an example. Is it correct that the $\mathbb{Q}$-automorphisms is determined up to associates? So since we have the associates $\{1,-1,i,-i\}$, we can send the generators of the extension to 4 different elements each...? Or is this totally wrong? (I'm kind of certain that this is wrong, but I'm looking for an explanation).

Comment: Yeah, but that is because it is an Q-automorphism? Like, will it be legit to send $\sqrt{3}$ and $\sqrt{2}$ to $\{\pm \sqrt{3}, \pm i \sqrt{3} \}$, $\{\pm \sqrt{2}, \pm i \sqrt{2} \}$ respectively?

Comment: By associate, I mean having the same norm.

Comment: I am not sure what you're trying to say...

Comment: Are you really thinking that because, $i$ has norm $1$ we can find a $\Bbb{Q}$-automorphism that sends $1$ to $i$?

Comment: The choices of the images of $\Bbb{Q}$-automorphisms are constrained by the fact that they must observe polynomial relations (= the relations that can be written using field operations only). We have $2=(\sqrt2)^2$, so if $\sigma$ is a $\Bbb{Q}$-automorphism, we must have
$$2=\sigma(2)=\sigma(\sqrt2^2)=\sigma(\sqrt2)^2.$$ Implying that $\sigma(\sqrt2)$ must be $\pm\sqrt2$.

Comment: It is true that the automorphism maps an element r to another root of the minimal polynomial of r over Q.

Comment: You seem to be asking about the possibility of a connection between the *Galois group* and the *group of units* of the associated ring of integers. Broadly speaking, there is none. Just take the simple example of $\Bbb Q(\sqrt2\,)$. Here, there are infinitely many units, namely $\pm1$ and the powers of $\sqrt2+1$. Infinitely many! But the Galois group is the humble and very finite group of order $2$.